# Doctrine does not sync with database after MySql update to 5.7.20

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

After update to mysql 5.7.20 (10.2.11-MariaDB-10.2.11+maria~xenial-log) doctrine does NOT recognize columns with default value NULL.

It keeps on generating queries like:
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE date_added date_added DATETIME DEFAULT NULL....
for every nullable column in the database even after I execute them.

MySQL mode is: NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Doctrine Version: ~2.5.3

I found out that in INFORMATION_SCHEMA database and COLUMNS table the column named 'COLUMN_DEFAULT' for all nullable columns has the value 'NULL'(as string) where in the old version is null (as NULL in mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB 10.2 is not yet supported by the Doctrine DBAL, and judging by the discussion in their issue tracker, we won't get a fix until the next minor version release (2.7) .

Source: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2825